# htaccess redirect a url with a param and remove duplicates

Tags: .htaccess

I have this url

```
http://www.mmametals.com.php5-20.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/?page_id=61
```

and i want to redirect to the root like this

```
http://www.mmametals.com.php5-20.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com
```

here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
redirect 301 /?page_id=61/ http://www.mmametals.com.php5-20.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com
```

but nothing is happening...any ideas

Also I was wondering if there is a way also in .htaccess to delete a duplicate /about ...so for example if the url is

```
 http://somesite.com/about/about
```

it will rewrite the rule to always be

```
 http://somesite.com/about
```

Comment: With your first example, are you trying to just remove all query strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=61$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mmametals.com.php5-20.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^/about/about[/]?
RewriteRule (.*) http://somesite.com/about? [R=301,L]
```

should do it.

Comment: awesome thanks ...one last thing....what if there is a param at the end of about/about?ref=apples is there a way to keep that like http://somesite.com/about?ref=apples

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer off the top of my head as I don't work directly with apache that much any longer, but I think you need to look into apache's mod_rewrite module.  Try taking a look at:

- [Apache's mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [This post about blocking certain URLS](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/02/03/eight-ways-to-blacklist-with-apaches-mod_rewrite/)